# How can I safely gzip and remove a file if I want to append to an existing .gz file if it exists?

Tags: bash, shell, find, gzip, xargs

My script currently looks like this:

```
find Logs/ -type f -name \*.log -exec gzip -q -9 {} \;
```

Right now this fails if myLog.log.gz already exists. Instead I want to append to myLog.log.gz. The gzip manual page says you can do this with something like `gzip -c myLog.log >> myLog.log.gz`. But this doesn't delete myLog.log when its done gzipping.

How can I safely gzip and remove the file, appending to an existing .gz if necessary?

Comment: It shouldn't, since you're matching on `*.log` - it shouldn't match `*.log.gz`. That'd require `*.log*`.

Comment: It shouldn't fail? It fails if I have both myLog.log and myLog.log.gz in the same directory because gzip doesn't want to overwrite myLog.log.gz

Comment: yes but note that the example in man page is `gzip -c file1  > foo.gz; gzip -c file2 >> foo.gz` . The file names being concatenated are different than the gz file. What you have will messup your existing myLog.log.gz, OR at least cause a lot of duplicate data being stored into the .gz file, i.e. `ver1log>> log.gz ; ver2log >>log.gz ver3log>> log.gz` Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, depending on what you want to do (e.g. just for archiving purposes), it might be more appropriate to just `tar` the two files or something along those lines. However, below is as you explained your requirements.

I really hope :) there's a more concise way to do this, but lacking that one this [will do the job](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/version-1-sucks-but-ship-it-anyway.html):

```
find logs -type f -name \*.log -exec sh -c '
if [ -f "{}.gz" ]; then
  tmpf=`mktemp tmpXXX`
  mv "{}" $tmpf
  gunzip "{}"
  cat $tmpf >> "{}"
  gzip "{}"
  rm $tmpf
else
  gzip {}
fi
' \;
```

Here's a small test script - put the above in `gzip-combine.sh`, the below in `test-gzip-combine.sh` and run it in some temporary folder (as you can see, it deletes `logs` under that folder, so don't run it somewhere where you actually have logs :))):

```
# Make sample logs
rm -rf logs
mkdir logs
echo "hello" > logs/a.log
gzip logs/a.log
echo "world" > logs/a.log
echo "miss" > logs/b.log
echo "think" > logs/c.log

# Run
./gzip-combine.sh

# Test
for i in logs/*; do
  echo ---- $i
  gzip -l $i
  gunzip -c $i
done
```

The output will be something like this:

```
$ ./test-gzip-combine.sh 
---- logs/a.log.gz
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
                 38                  12  50.0% logs/a.log
hello
world
---- logs/b.log.gz
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
                 31                   5 120.0% logs/b.log
miss
---- logs/c.log.gz
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
                 32                   6 100.0% logs/c.log
think
```

So you can see it combined `a.log` having `world` in it and `a.log.gz`, a result of `gzip logs/a.log` above, having `hello` in it.

Obviously not fool-proof for many reasons (e.g. if you run out of disk space, run out of electricity or your logs are 1GB each or things like that), but for most regular applications it should do the job.

Hope this helps.